# Why does a partially hidden JFrame not repaint properly on Linux when switching between virtual desktops

Tags: java, linux, user-interface, swing, repaint

we have problems with Java 6 applications that do not properly refresh when switching virtual desktops. The problem so far has been reproduced on Fedora 11 and 13 with GNOME and Suse SLES 10 with KDE. I use the following test case to reproduce the problem:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class RepaintTest {
    private JLabel label;

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("RepaintTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        label = new JLabel("Repaint Test");
        label.setOpaque(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final RepaintTest repaintTest = new RepaintTest();
                repaintTest.createAndShowGUI();
                new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
                    boolean flip;
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        repaintTest.label.setBackground(flip ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED);
                        flip = !flip;
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Start this program and move another window, for example, a terminal window, partially in front of it. Wait for the window background to become red, switch to another virtual desktop and wait for five seconds, then switch back to your original screen. The background now should be completely green. Instead, what I get is a window that is only partially updated in the visible parts not covered by the other window.

This problem does not occur with Java 5 and it does not occur when using one of the following properties at startup:

```
-Dswing.handleTopLevelPaint=false
```

or

```
-Dswing.bufferPerWindow=false
```

However, turning off Swing's double buffering seems not to be a very good option. Is this a JDK bug on Linux or can we do anything in our applications to fix this repaint problem?

Comment: At first, extending the JFrame class is useless in your case, as you don't make any use of it. Not sure, but this could also cause the error Try just removing extends JFrame.

Comment: Removing "extends JFrame" does not change the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your `TimerTask` needs to change the label on the event dispatch thread, e.g.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    boolean flip;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                repaintTest.label.setBackground(flip ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED);
                flip = !flip;
            }
        });
    }
}, 5000, 5000);
```

More conveniently, use [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), as its action event handler executes on the event-dispatching thread.

Comment: You are right. I messed this up while trying to create a small reproducible test case. I will fix this and update my question. However, I can still reproduce the original problem with the fixed version.

Comment: @Mark: I'm not seeing a problem on Ubuntu 10.04.1.

Comment: Strange. I can reproduce the problem also on Ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10 with JDK 1.6.0_21 x86_64.

Comment: @Mark: No problems on Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS, OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.2) or Mac OS X 10.5.8, JDK 1.6.0_22.

Answer (score 1):

I tested with multiple jdks: sun 64bit 1.6.0_04 server vm, 1.6.0_21 server+client vm and openjdk 64bit 1.6.0_20 server + client vm on my ubuntu x64 10.10: all look the same, update does not work. And I also noted that it differs depending on where to cover the java window:

- putting another window with the upper-left corner over the java window: only a small horizontal line is not updated
- putting another window with the lower-eft corner over the java window: the rectangle left from the covering window is not updated
- putting another window with the left/right side over the java window: background is updated as expected

Update behaviour with upper/lower-right sides differ the same way.

It does not make any difference if testing on primary or secondary screen.

And I can confirm it is working

- with sun 32bit jdk 1.5.0_10 server vm.
- with 1.6.0_21 x86 ON WINDOWS XP using dexpot as virtual desktops manager

If the 1.5 java would not work I would have guessed it to be a XX/graphics card driver related issue. But with this working it seems related to the java vm.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I guess it's time now for reporting this to Oracle as it seems to be a JDK bug.